# how get CSV FILE from the FTP server to local drive using extended stored procedures

Tags: c#, xsp

Please give example to get file (auto) from FTP server to local machine with the help of extended stored procedures in in c# application

Comment: "Stored procedures" is a feature many SQL servers support; why should this be needed for use with the **File** Transfer Protocol. You are consusing things. Also, what is an auto-file? What have you tried so far? Where **exactly** is your problem?

Comment: I am creating an application which import Csv file from Ftp server  so firstly it check new file in Ftp server ,if file (CSV file) exists than it  download it into local drive .

Comment: Extended stored procedures use COM DLLs (and run in the SQL Server's address space and are generally not advisable).  Beginning with SQL Server 2005, you can write CLR stored procedures using the .NET language of your choice. Neither of which make any sense in the context of a "c# application." Please edit your question for clarity.  Also, link to msdn on xp vs clr http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlnetfx/thread/387dedd6-005e-40eb-a0ac-fe22e3ea6ef1

Comment: SQL has really nothing to do with FTP. I think you first need some very basic introduction to Computer stuff in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your point you may not inteding the SQL Stored procedures.
you can from C# do the following

//Get List of Files on the FTP

```
    public string[] GetFileList(string URL)
            {
                string[] downloadFiles;
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
                string ftpUserID = "xyz";
                string ftpPassword = "123";
                try
                {

                    reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(URL));
                    reqFTP.UseBinary = true;    
                    reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
                    reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
                    reqFTP.Proxy = null;
                    WebResponse response = reqFTP.GetResponse();
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                    //MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();
                    while (line != null)
                    {
                       ProcessGotFile(line);

                        result.Append(line);
                        result.Append("\n");
                        line = reader.ReadLine();
                    }
                    result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf('\n'), 1);
                    reader.Close();
                    response.Close();
                    //MessageBox.Show(response.StatusDescription);
                    return result.ToString().Split('\n');
                }

    public void ProcessGotFile(string line)
            {
               string message_id;
               FTPclient ftp = new FTPclient();
               // download the file
               Download(@"D:\", line, "ftp://xyz:123@ftp.theFTP.com");
// Here you got `the` file locally and can start deal with it through the FileInfo class
            }

     public void Download(string filePath, string fileName, string URL)
            {
                FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
                try
                {

                    string ftpUserID = "xyz";
                    string ftpPassword = "123";
                    //filePath = <<The full path where the file is to be created.>>, 
                    //fileName = <<Name of the file to be created(Need not be the name of the file on FTP server).>>
                    FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(filePath
    + "\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create);

                    reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(URL + fileName));
                    reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

                    reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
                    reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
                    reqFTP.Timeout = 500000;
                    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
                    Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    long cl = response.ContentLength;
                    int bufferSize = 2048;
                    int readCount;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                    readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    while (readCount > 0)
                    {
                        outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                        readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    }


                    ftpStream.Close();
                    outputStream.Close();
                    response.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

I hope this help you.